# how to add multiple line commenting in wpf xaml file?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

```
   <Grid Name="grid2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,5,10,10" TextBlock.Foreground="White">
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   </Grid>
```

I want to comment the lines regarding grid2

Comment: multiple line commenting..!!

Comment: Considered using the standard approach? Markt it all, CTRL-K, CTRL-C

Comment: Try the shortcut CTRL + K, C

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To comment in Visual Studio

Select the lines,

```
CTRL+K +C
```

UNcomment

```
CTRL+K+U
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference in XML (and thus XAML) between multi-line and single-line commenting:

```
<!-- single line -->
```

Vs.

```
<!--
  multi
  line
-->
```

To help you there are [shortcuts available in Visual Studio](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2013/), like commented by others:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>C</kbd>: Comment
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>U</kbd>: Uncomment

Comment: Is it possible to have Visual Studio add multiple single line comments, instead of breaking it up into one multi line comment?

Comment: Not as far as I know

Comment: The self typed html style commenting does not seem to work in VS. Whereas the short cuts work fine!